# load image change with fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, fade

I want to change an image with fade effects when I click on a different image on the page (an image of an arrow).

I have a script and am having trouble getting the arrow image to load the function.

the html:

```
<img id="change_image" class="blockdisplay" src="Img/onetoone_1.jpg" height="80%">

<input id="change_image" type="image" src="Img/array_arrow_right.jpg" class="blockdisplay" height=12.5px width 12.5px >
```

and the script:

```
var images = ("Img/onetoone_1.jpg","Img/onetoone_2.jpg","Img/onetoone_3.jpg","Img/onetoone_4.jpg","Img/onetoone_5.jpg","Img/onetoone_6.jpg");

$(document).ready(function(){
var image_number = 0;
// Click handler to change images
$("#change_image").click(function(){
    // Get number of next image (loop)
    image_number = (image_number + 1) % images.length;
    // Make sure the image is loaded (if not, preload it)
    $("<img>").attr("src", images[image_number]).load(function(){
        // As soon as the next image is loaded, fade out the current one...
        $("#image").fadeOut(function(){
            // ...and fade in the new image :)
            $(this).attr("src", images[image_number]).fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

});

Comment: any help would be great !

Comment: you're using the same id for the image and for the input, that is not valid, **id attributes should be unique in a HTML page**

Comment: For starts, you'll need to change the variable `images` to an array using square brackets.